# Kotlin collections and objects sum

Tags: android, kotlin, collections

I have following classes:

```
class UserData(
        val firstSale: Date,
        val lastSale: Date,
        val ptuCodesList: List<ItemSale>,
        val taxList: List<ItemSale>,
        val salesList: List<ItemSale>,
        val taxTotal: Long,
        val saleTotal: Long,
        val currency: String = DEAFULT_CURRENCY,
        val canceledOrderCount: Int,
        val canceledSaleTotal: Long,
)
```

And model class:

```
class ItemSale(
       val itemDescription: String,
       val itemsTotalValue: Long
)
```

I'm fetchig all my UserData objects from my db

```
dbRepository.getAllUsersData(): List<UserData>
```

And now i dont know how to sum this List UserData objects and return as single object i mean, i have no idea how to sum those lists taxList/saleList included in UserData object. In those lists i need to sum itemsTotalValue.

Example:

We have list of two UserData objects:

```
class UserData(
        val firstSale: 238402384092L,
        val lastSale: 893231117482L,
        val ptuCodesList: List<ItemSale>,
        val taxList: List<ItemSale>, -> ("first", 4), ("second", 4)
        val salesList: List<ItemSale>, -> ("third", 5), ("fourth", 3)
        val taxTotal: 500,
        val saleTotal: 600,
        val currency: String = DEAFULT_CURRENCY,
        val canceledOrderCount: 3,
        val canceledSaleTotal: 4500
)

class UserData(
        val firstSale: 338402384092L,
        val lastSale: 9934798237482L,
        val ptuCodesList: List<ItemSale>,
        val taxList: List<ItemSale>, -> ("first", 7), ("second", 8)
        val salesList: List<ItemSale>, -> ("third", 1), ("fourth", 2)
        val taxTotal: 250,
        val saleTotal: 400,
        val currency: String = DEAFULT_CURRENCY,
        val canceledOrderCount: 4,
        val canceledSaleTotal: 400
)
```

Result:

```
class UserData(
        val firstSale: 238402384092L,
        val lastSale: 9934798237482L,
        val ptuCodesList: List<ItemSale>, //Stay same for all objects
        val taxList: List<ItemSale>, // ("first", 11), ("second", 12)
        val salesList: List<ItemSale>, // ("third", 6), ("fourth", 5)
        val taxTotal: 750,
        val saleTotal: 1000,
        val currency: String = DEAFULT_CURRENCY, // Stay for all same
        val canceledOrderCount: 7,
        val canceledSaleTotal: 4900
)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like this:

```
  listOfUserData.map{ it.salesList.map{ it.itemsTotalValue }.sum() }.sum()
```

A simplified but complete example:

```
class UserData(val salesList: List<ItemSale>, val taxList: List<ItemSale>)

class ItemSale(
   val itemDescription: String,
   val itemsTotalValue: Long
)

fun main() {

    val itemSale1 = ItemSale("A", 12) 
    val itemSale2 = ItemSale("B", 30) 
    val itemSale3 = ItemSale("C", 45) 
    val itemSale4 = ItemSale("D", 55)
    val itemSale5 = ItemSale("E", 23)
    val itemSale6 = ItemSale("F",  2)

    val listOfUserData = listOf(UserData(listOf(itemSale1, itemSale2), 
                                         listOf(itemSale5)),
                                UserData(listOf(itemSale3, itemSale4), 
                                         listOf(itemSale6)) )

    val sumSales = listOfUserData.map{ it.salesList.map{ it.itemsTotalValue }.sum() }.sum()
    val sumTax   = listOfUserData.map{ it.taxList.map{ it.itemsTotalValue }.sum() }.sum() 

    val sum      = listOfUserData.map{ it.salesList.map{ it.itemsTotalValue }.sum() }.sum() + 
                   listOfUserData.map{ it.taxList.map{ it.itemsTotalValue }.sum() }.sum()       


    println(sumSales)   // 142
    println(sumTax)     //  25 
    println(sum)        // 167

 }
```

UPDATE for merging objects:

```
 val itemSale1 = ItemSale("A", 12)
 val itemSale2 = ItemSale("B", 30)
 val itemSale3 = ItemSale("C", 45)
 val itemSale4 = ItemSale("D", 55)
 val itemSale5 = ItemSale("A", 13)
 val itemSale6 = ItemSale("B", 29)
 val itemSale7 = ItemSale("C", 32)
 val itemSale8 = ItemSale("D", 21)

 val myMap = mutableMapOf<String, Long>()

 val listOfUserData = listOf(UserData(listOf(itemSale1, itemSale2),
                                      listOf(itemSale3, itemSale4)),
                             UserData(listOf(itemSale5, itemSale6),
                                      listOf(itemSale7, itemSale8)) )

 listOfUserData.map{ it.salesList.map{ myMap[it.itemDescription] = myMap.getOrDefault(it.itemDescription, 0L) + it.itemsTotalValue }}

 println(myMap)   // {A=25, B=59}
```

Kotlin Playground

https://pl.kotl.in/aiGawyaJQ

Comment: I've added example to my question for better understanding :)

Comment: The point is that, list size is not constant it can be 0..n

Comment: String description is constant for all those objects, but value is not

Comment: One more idea: read the variable into a map - see update section in post.

Answer (score 1):

It's still unclear what you want to happen when "summing" two UserDatas with different `firstSale`, `lastSale`, or `currency`. Anyway, I would write a function that adds two UserData together, handling these cases however you intend to, for example:

```
fun List<ItemSale>.aggregateWith(other: List<ItemSale>): List<ItemSale> {
    return (this + other).groupBy(ItemSale::itemDescription)
        .entries
        .map { ItemSale(it.key, it.value.map(ItemSale::itemsTotalValue).sum() )}
}

data class UserData(
    val firstSale: Date,
    val lastSale: Date,
    val ptuCodesList: List<ItemSale>,
    val taxList: List<ItemSale>,
    val salesList: List<ItemSale>,
    val taxTotal: Long,
    val saleTotal: Long,
    val currency: String,
    val canceledOrderCount: Int,
    val canceledSaleTotal: Long,
) {
    operator fun plus(other: UserData): UserData {
        if (other.firstSale != firstSale || other.lastSale != lastSale || other.currency != currency) {
            error("Cannot add mismatched UserData $this to $other.")
        }
        return copy(
            ptuCodesList = ptuCodesList.aggregateWith(other.ptuCodesList),
            taxList = taxList.aggregateWith(other.taxList),
            salesList = salesList.aggregateWith(other.salesList),
            taxTotal = taxTotal + other.taxTotal,
            saleTotal = saleTotal + other.saleTotal,
            canceledOrderCount = canceledOrderCount + other.canceledOrderCount,
            canceledSaleTotal = canceledSaleTotal + other.canceledSaleTotal
        )
    }
}
```

Then you can `reduce` the list to get what you want:

```
fun List<UserData>.aggregate(): UserData = reduce(UserData::plus)
```

Comment: first sale i will take from first item in list, but last sale date i will take from last object in list, some of those variables will stay constant like:  itemDescription in ItemSale

Comment: OK, so can you figure it out from what I put? Just modify the `plus` function to do what you want when combining two objects.

Comment: I've edited my example again to be more specific. But i cant figure out from your answer how to achiive my goal. Sorry i'm not that good in kotlin yet :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sumByDouble`

```
class UserData(
    val firstSale: Date,
    val lastSale: Date,
    val ptuCodesList: List<ItemSale>,
    val taxList: List<ItemSale>,
    val salesList: List<ItemSale>,
    val taxTotal: Long,
    val saleTotal: Long,
    val currency: String = DEAFULT_CURRENCY,
    val resignOrderCount: Int,
    val canceledSaleTotal: Long,
    val fiscalEventsCount: Int,
    val nonFiscalPrintoutsCount: Int
){
    val sumOfTaxAndSales: Long
      get() = taxList.sumByDouble { it.itemsTotalValue.toDouble() }.toLong() + salesList.sumByDouble { it.itemsTotalValue.toDouble() }.toLong()
}
```

Comment: I dont need to add taxList to saleList. I need to 1:1 sum all numbers in UserData list including those in (itemsTotalValue)  nested list

Comment: can you add example to elaborate your expectation ?

Comment: i've changed little bit my class and i've added example. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to maintain **Long** as your sum result, you could use map function. For example:

```
val taxListSum = taxList.map { it.itemsTotalValue }.sum()
```

I suggest this because so far Kotlin only provides *sumBy* (which returns an Int) and *sumByDouble* to sum concrete properties over collections.

Comment: I've added example to my question to simplify little bit my question :)